# why are all my android studio projects named app

Tags: android, project

I'm starting to use Android Studio.

I've used several first android app tutorials such as 'HelloWorld' etc.

I've followed the instructions to the letter and yet all my projects are named app, not the project name.

'HelloWorld' is at the root of the project directory, but underneath the gradle folder the app folder is named 'app' not HelloWorld.

Any help with this much appreciated. Apologies in advance if the solution to this is embarrassingly obvious.

Comment: You can refactor this folder. Mac -> CMD + F6

Comment: Thanks TeRRo. I think that's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "project" is actually a module.

I may be wrong but, when you create a project it also creates a module. That module is a folder containing the main application files. By default, it is called "app" because, well... that's where you app files are. You can rename it by right clicking it and refactoring it.

[image]